# Attempting to list noflo node modules leads to Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, noflo

I'm following [the documentation](http://noflojs.org/documentation/)
on how to get NoFlo up and running. Just prior to the section
"Defining your first graph" there is a line which says that I can see
the list of installed componenents by typing

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/noflo list .
```

However, doing so leads to the stack backtrace below. The first few
lines of the program that noflo is barfing on are:

```
if typeof process isnt 'undefined' and process.execPath and process.execPath.indexOf('node') isnt -1
  noflo = require "../../lib/NoFlo"
else
  noflo = require '../lib/NoFlo'

class Graph extends noflo.Component
  constructor: ->
    @network = null
    @ready = true
    @started = false
    @baseDir = null
    @loader = null
```

### Transcript of shell session follows

tbrannon@tbrannon0:~/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app$ ./node_modules/.bin/noflo list .

/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/src/components/Graph.coffee:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { if typeof proces
                                                                 ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token typeof
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at ComponentLoader.load (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/ComponentLoader.js:127:26)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/bin/noflo.js:115:36
  at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/bin/noflo.js:113:18
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:132:16
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:758:21
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:152:18
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:39:16
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:758:21
  at ComponentLoader.getModuleComponents (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:61:16)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:146:22
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:118:5
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at asyncMap (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:27:18)
  at next (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:200:5)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:157:7
  at LOOP (fs.js:1356:14)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

tbrannon@tbrannon0:~/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-app$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by an [API change in CoffeeScript 1.7](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog). [A fix](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/pull/132) was made in NoFlo's git repository.

The fix was included in [NoFlo 0.4.4](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/blob/master/CHANGES.md#044-february-4th-2014) available via NPM.